# what is the best method for accessing MySQL from Android device

Tags: android, mysql

I have a question,

what is the best method for accessing MySQL database from Android device :

1. JSON (require http server for json parsing).
2. XML (require http server for xml parsing).
3. JDBC (not require http server, but it more slowly, I think).
4. or any method, please tell me ...

please give me any suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Serving up `JSON` over `HTTP` from a simple web service is probably the best way. I personally recommend using Python and the [Flask micro-framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for small API's.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go the JDBC route, I think that's absolutely your best bet.  the mySQL database is what's doing the work, not the transport mechanism. So, the JDBC is going to just delivery the query and then get you back your result. At least that's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinition, **JSON is the best** among others like XML.

Why?

Just because its to create and return JSON from web and also very much easy to implement JSON Parsing in Android programming side. While XML parsing is much more difficult as compared to JSON. And also its also hard to create XML structure at web.